# How can I see the Monodevelop patch in bug#606470

Tags: launchpad, mono, appmenu

https://bugs.launchpad.net/dbusmenu/+bug/606470/comments/3

Shows a patch which fixes the missing unity menu workaround. I'd like to see what this patch does so I can apply it to my MD trunk build (and maybe make a pull request upstream). Is there a way I can browse this diff in launchpad?

I think I really want an easy way to find revision 2.4+dfsg-3ubuntu2 in whatever source tree holds ubuntu monodevelop packages

UPDATE:
I found this : https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/monodevelop

UPDATE:
I finally found this: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/natty/monodevelop/natty/revision/53?start_revid=53

monodevelop.in just gets used to generate the menu entry.

I'd like a more general solution, like dynamic menu support from libappmenu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packaging for applications is kept in bzr; in this case you'd need to find the packaging branch, it's referrenced [in the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dbusmenu/+bug/606470), just easy to miss.

[image]

This takes us to:

- https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/maverick/monodevelop/maverick

and the patch you actually want:

- http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/maverick/monodevelop/maverick/view/head:/debian/patches/no_appmenu